# Square-integrability in lemma 4.30 of Folland's "A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis"

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups

*Update: I decided to post the question on MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/370560/164599).*

In lemma 4.30 of Folland's "A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis" (Second Edition) one needs to show the square-integrability of the function $f$ defined below and I don't understand how Folland deduces it from the inequality below.

[image]

[image]

For context, $G$ is a locally compact abelian Hausdorff group and $dx$ is the Haar measure on $G$ (note that Folland defines Radon measures to be outer regular and inner regular on open sets). Furthermore $f$ is continuous, bounded and a linear combination of functions of positive type (this is encoded in the notation $f \in \mathcal{B}(G)$). Here is what i have tried so far:

With Plancherel's theorem we see (as in Folland's proof) that $$(L^1(G) \cap L^2(G), \|\cdot\|_2) \to \mathbb{C}, \ k \mapsto \int_G f(x) \cdot k(x) \, dx$$ defines a bounded linear functional which extends to a bounded linear functional $F \in L^2(G)^*$ by the BLT theorem (I removed the complex conjugation for linearity; this should not make a difference in the argumentation).

Now Riesz's theorem yields an $r \in \mathcal{L}^2(G)$ such that $F$ is given by integration against $r$, i.e. $$F(k) = \int_G r(x) \cdot k(x) \, dx \ \text{ for all } k \in L^2(G).$$
In particular we have $$\int_G f(x) \cdot k(x) \, dx = \int_G r(x) \cdot k(x) \, dx \ \text{ for all } k \in L^1(G) \cap L^2(G).$$

With this we can show that the set $N := \{x \in G: r(x) \neq f(x)\}$ is locally null with respect to the Haar measure $dx$ since for any Borel set $A \subseteq N$ with finite Haar measure we can set $$k(x) := 1_A(x) \cdot \frac{|f(x) - r(x)|}{(f(x) - r(x)) + 1_{G \setminus N}(x)}$$ to obtain a function $k \in L^1(G) \cap L^2(G)$, so $$0 = \int_G (f(x) - r(x)) \cdot k(x) \, dx = \int_A |f(x) - r(x)| \, dx,$$
i.e. $A \cap N = A$ has Haar measure $0$.

To show $f \in L^2(G)$ we can now equivalently show that $N$ has Haar measure $0$ (it is clear that this is sufficient and it also is necessary by the injectivity of the map in Riesz's theorem), but I haven't managed to reach this conclusion - the claim would follow from the above argumentation if our Haar measure was inner regular on $N$, but I also don't see why this would be the case.

EDIT:

It is sufficient to show that $N$ is $\sigma$-finite and this problem can be reduced further: The set $$R := \{x \in G: r(x) \neq 0\} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{x \in G: |r(x)| \geq \tfrac{1}{n}\}$$ is $\sigma$-finite since $r \in \mathcal{L}^2(G)$, so $R \cap N$ is again $\sigma$-finite and locally null. Hence $R \cap N$ has Haar measure $0$ and we only need to worry about the set $$M := (G \setminus R) \cap N = \{x \in G: r(x) = 0 \neq f(x)\}.$$

Comment: That looks like Hölder inequality but I may be wrong since I haven't read that book.

Comment: I don't see how Hölder's inequality helps with the square-integrability of $f$ here.

Comment: Note that $\|f\|_2^2=\sup_{\|g\|_2=1}|\int fg|$ where the sup is taken over a dense subset of $L^2$.

Comment: @julian Could you explain why this equality holds for $f$ in this case? For a general measure space $(X, \mu)$ it only holds if we already know that $f \in L^2(X)$ - take for example $X = \{x\}$ and define $\mu(X) := \infty$ and $\mu(\emptyset) := 0$. Then $L^2(X, \mu) = \{0\}$, i.e. the right side is $0$ for any measurable function $f$, but $\|1\|_2^2 = \infty$.

Comment: Well it certainly holds for semi-finite $\mu$ and the sup taken over the indicators of sets of finite measure, which is good enough for your problem.

Comment: Do you have an explanation/reference why this equality holds in the situation that you have stated? Furthermore i don't see why the Haar measure here is semi-finite - in fact, this would be equivalent to it being inner regular.

Comment: According to the guidelines I've decided to post the equivalence of inner regularity and semi-finiteness as a separate question and answer, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3808568/793374.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update:* The question has been solved on MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/370568/164599).